# How to use 'keydown ' eventHandler with 'IntersectionObserver' in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, slider, addeventlistener, keydown, intersection-observer

I am configuring a slider in JavaScript. For the same I have written following code.
**slides** is a NodeList of all 4 photos.
`sliderBtnLeft` is a left arrow
`sliderBtnRight` is a right arrow

there is a `goToSlide(slide)` function that is used to display the particular slide by adjusting the transformX.

there are 2 functions `nextSlideFn()` and `prevSlideFn()` that are called when corresponding buttons are pressed.

The code is working fine when I use buttons. The code also works okay when I use 'keydown' eventListener.

Problem arises when I try to use **'keydown' eventListener.** with the intersection observer.

It works okay the first time section comes in the viewport. Later on if I scroll up and scroll down again, the function after ArrowKey is pressed gets called 3 times.

Eg. If i press ArrowRight after scrolling up and down, `nextSlideFn()` gets called 3 times. And the number of times it gets called increases by 2 everytime I scroll up and down.

One up and down scroll: `nextSlideFn()` gets called 3 times
Twice up and down scroll: `nextSlideFn()` gets called 5 times
Thrice up and down scroll: `nextSlideFn()` gets called 7 times
and so on...

Same for ArrowLeft. (I checked it by logging it to the console)

There is some problem with the observer function `sliderFunction()` and `document.addEventListener('keydown',...)` when used together.
What might be the reason

//Code snippet

```
    const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
    const slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
    const sliderBtnLeft = document.querySelector('.slider__btn--left');
    const sliderBtnRight = document.querySelector('.slider__btn--right');
    
    let currentSlide = 0;
          
    
    const goToSlide = function(slide){
      slides.forEach((s, index) => {
        s.style.transform = `translateX(${100 * (index - slide)}%)`;
      });
    }
    
    goToSlide(0);
    
    const nextSlideFn = function(){
      (currentSlide === slides.length - 1) ? currentSlide = 0 : currentSlide++;
      console.log('Right pressed');
      goToSlide(currentSlide);
    };
    
    const prevSlideFn = function(){
      (currentSlide === 0) ? currentSlide = slides.length - 1 : currentSlide --;
      console.log('Left pressed');
      goToSlide(currentSlide);
    };
    
    sliderBtnRight.addEventListener('click', nextSlideFn);
    sliderBtnLeft.addEventListener('click', prevSlideFn);
    
    const slideObject = {
      root: null,
      threshold: 0,
    }
    
    const sliderFunction = function(entries,observer){
      const entry = entries[0];
      console.log(entry.target);
      
      document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    
        if(e.key === 'ArrowRight'){
          nextSlideFn();
        }
        if(e.key === 'ArrowLeft'){
           prevSlideFn();
        }
       }); 
   
    };
    
    const slideObserver = new IntersectionObserver(sliderFunction, slideObject);

    slideObserver.observe(slider);
```